# Man page renders with blanks on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: documentation, command-line

I'm using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Bash GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

My `man` pages blank all the options of a command like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out :))

The "blanks" aren't actually blank. It's just that the options are also black so they blend in with the background

Changing the terminal background fixed it.